# Custom Json String Format - Could this be written better/improved?

Tags: python, json

In Python 2.7, I am making a json string(api call return) that contains a list of unanswered threads. The way I have it right now, each thread is a array element. This works for me with no issues. But I am trying to improve my coding and I am wondering if this json string is organized/formatted correctly or could it be improved in it's format?

```
{
   "unanswered_threads":[
      {
         "thread_id":174,
         "author_username":"BP",
         "latest_post_date":"2014-02-18T03:37:21.67",
         "latest_reply_author":684,
         "url":"https://community.com/products/t/334.aspx",
         "reply_count":2,
         "forum_id":18,
         "author_name":"ABP",
         "subject":"Storage App"
      },
      {
         "thread_id":335,
         "author_username":"wigv",
         "latest_post_date":"2014-02-18T02:13:29.183",
         "latest_reply_author":649,
         "url":"https://community.com/products/t/375.aspx",
         "reply_count":2,
         "forum_id":45,
         "author_name":"wigsv",
         "subject":"configuration - RPC-2.1"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is how I generate this json string:

```
threads =  r.json()["Threads"]
thread_batch = []

for thread in thread_generator(threads):
    thread_batch.append(thread)

json_return = json.dumps({ "unanswered_threads": thread_batch });
```

Comment: Are you wondering on the JSON *format* or the structure of the data you are returning? Are you producing with the `json` module or did you format this with your own code?

Comment: I created and formatted this Json with my own code. Yes, I am wondering on the format and structure.

Comment: Why the reinvention of the wheel?

Comment: Perhaps there is a misunderstanding, I am using the json.dumps() if that is what you mean.

Comment: Right, there was a misunderstanding. So then the question is limited to just 'is this a good structure', which is hard to say without knowing your detailed application requirements and largely comes down to opinion anyway. Most of all, such questions are rather off-topic for Stack Overflow..

Comment: I disagree, there is always conventions and best practices and I was looking to improve my Json writing according to such.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't make such questions on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: That largely comes down to opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSONlint](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint) say it's valid. I usually end up with something closer to this:

```
{
    "unanswered_threads": [{
        "thread_id": 174,
            "author_username": "BP",
            "latest_post_date": "2014-02-18T03:37:21.67",
            "latest_reply_author": 684,
            "url": "https://community.com/products/t/334.aspx",
            "reply_count": 2,
            "forum_id": 18,
            "author_name": "ABP",
            "subject": "Storage App"
    }, {
        "thread_id": 335,
            "author_username": "wigv",
            "latest_post_date": "2014-02-18T02:13:29.183",
            "latest_reply_author": 649,
            "url": "https://community.com/products/t/375.aspx",
            "reply_count": 2,
            "forum_id": 45,
            "author_name": "wigsv",
            "subject": "configuration - RPC-2.1"
    }]
}
```

But the difference is minuscule: spacing after `:` and put `}]` on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the [json module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)?  Then you just need to put your data into a python dictionary and use the json.dump method.